# Ruby On Rails: make text_field displaying the content from another text_field while editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, textfield

I am fresh of ruby on rails and have a question about how to display a input on multiple text_fields.
For example, I have two textfields called name and path. While I type "Project" in name textfield, I want the the path textfield can display "/path/Project".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlU4I.png)

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :project_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :path %>
    <%= form.text_field :path, id: :project_path, :readonly => true  %>
  </div>
```

Any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: Create a javascript method and call it oninput of text field name.

Comment: in which file, the posted code resides?

Comment: As AliAkbar says, if you want stuff to change before it hits the server (i.e. in real time) you'll need to use Javascript.

Comment: Thank you. Ali and Mark, I am going to see how to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a JS/Jquery little help, see:

```js
var $projectNameField = $('#project_name');
var $readOnlyField = $('#project_path');

$projectNameField.on('change', function() {
  var inputText = $projectNameField.val();
  $readOnlyField.val(inputText);
})
```

When some text was added to `project_name` it will be replied in `project_path`

Comment: Thank you for help. That is what I want.